# Why didn't anyone realize that Ryan was committing fraud?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-office

In the episode [Night Out](https://www.officequotes.net/no4-11.php), Ryan says:

> Yes, I’m having the Scranton branch come in on one Saturday **so they
> can re-enter sales that they made on the phone as sales that were made
> by the website which they should have done in the first place, if the
> website had been working**.

and later on:

> Dwight: Why am I being forced to come in tomorrow and pretend that a website made sales that I made?
>
> Ryan: This is a temporary measure to **increase the legitimacy of the site**.

Later, in [Goodbye Toby](https://www.officequotes.net/no4-14.php), it's stated:

> Oscar: Well this is what happened: uh, Ryan’s big project was the
> website… which wasn’t doing so well. **So Ryan, to give the impression
> of sales, recorded them twice: once as office sales, once as website
> sales.** Which is what we refer to in the business as “misleading the
> shareholders.” Another good term is “fraud.”

So when Ryan first suggested this in Night Out, why didn't anyone question why Ryan wanted them to input their sales twice? In other words, why didn't any red flags get raised? Sure, Dwight asked, but Ryan is asking them to lie, why didn't anyone question this further? Perhaps Oscar. It seems shady and unethical.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! Your question was in danger of being closed as you were asking multiple questions at once. As it happened, your first question seemed off-topic as it was entirely speculative; we can't say what *might* have happened, we can only analyse what *did* happen. So I've removed the first question to focus entirely on the one in the title (i.e. why nobody questioned the fraud or tried to prevent it); if you still want to ask your other question, please post it separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the audience clearly realize what's going on, I always figured it was to illustrate how little the Scranton employees cared for or, in some cases, knew about their work, and likely to paint the "golden child" Ryan as someone who bit off more than he can chew.

As season 4 progresses Ryan loses the respect of the Scranton branch as he becomes more obnoxious and pompous, but this moment also ushers in the beginning of his professional downfall.

Comment: For me it wasn’t clear that they weren’t also deducting.the person made sales while they were adding the web site sales.